# System Design Across countries data

Tags: architecture

This system design question is making me crazy.

Because of PII, the data is stored in its own country
i.e A user from USA data stored in USA and a user from India data stored in India.

So for a company like facebook, how do they maitain latency
a simple example
Indian user open profile of a user from USA.

How do they manage

1. latency
2. permisssion to view profile

Please help

Comment: As I understand PII is applicable for financial institutions and not for facebook. So when person from India who wants to access PII on his / her bank account will be facing latency.

Comment: @Geek all details of an id is PII like education,photo,email,phone

Comment: When say a " user from USA" do you mean a user physically located in the USA or a user that is a citizen of the USA? Also where is the PII rule that says that that data must be stored in a specific country?

Comment: such this is a rule that data need to be stored locally

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question without more context, but different types of information need to comply to very different regulations.

It is simply not true that PII needs to be stored in your "own country", and as per your facebook example: it is definitely not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Managing latency and access permissions in a global system with distributed data centers involves a combination of strategies and technologies. Here's how large platforms like Facebook might handle it:

#### 1. **Content Delivery Networks (CDN):**

- Use a global Content Delivery Network to distribute static content (like images, stylesheets) closer to the user, reducing latency.
- CDNs cache content on servers distributed worldwide, so when an Indian user accesses a profile from the USA, static content loads quickly from a nearby CDN server.

#### 2. **Edge Computing:**

- Employ edge computing to process requests closer to the user.
- Distribute some computing resources closer to the edge of the network to reduce the round-trip time for data to travel between the user and the server.

#### 3. **Data Sharding and Replication:**

- Shard data based on geographical regions. Each shard contains data for users in a specific location.
- Replicate frequently accessed data across multiple data centers to enhance availability and reduce latency.

#### 4. **GeoDNS:**

- Use Geographic Domain Name System (GeoDNS) to direct users to the nearest data center based on their location.
- This ensures that users are connected to servers that are physically closer, reducing latency.

#### 5. **Access Controls and Permissions:**

- Implement robust access control mechanisms to manage permissions.
- Authenticate users and check their permissions before allowing access to specific data.
- Role-based access control (RBAC) can be implemented to ensure that users only see what they're authorized to see.

#### 6. **Asynchronous Loading:**

- Load non-essential or less frequently accessed data asynchronously. For instance, load comments or less critical information after the primary content has loaded.

#### 7. **Predictive Loading:**

- Predict user behavior and preload data that is likely to be requested.
- Facebook might use machine learning algorithms to predict what data a user is likely to access based on their previous behavior.

#### 8. **Data Encryption and Compliance:**

- Implement strong data encryption measures to ensure compliance with privacy regulations.
- Ensure that data stored in different regions complies with local data protection laws.

#### 9. **Dynamic Caching:**

- Use dynamic caching strategies to cache data that is accessed frequently.
- Adjust caching strategies dynamically based on usage patterns.

#### 10. **Global Load Balancing:**

- Employ global load balancing to distribute incoming network traffic across multiple servers.
- Distribute traffic intelligently based on factors like server load and geographic location.

Large-scale platforms like Facebook invest heavily in infrastructure and technologies to provide a seamless experience for users worldwide, while also ensuring compliance with data privacy laws.